# Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Order) with the same id already exist after Plesk Upgrade

Tags: database, collection

I've just upgraded MySQL as recommended by Plesk and we're now being hit with the following error when trying to access Sales -> Orders;

> Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Order) with the same id "56321" already exist

Could this have been caused by the update? it wasn't a big update just an incremental one (we're on 5.5.54)

Any help is greatly appreciated

**EDIT:**
I did actually place a test order on the site and deleted it shortly after using Magehit's extension Delete Order.

I assumed this wouldn't cause an issue as we've done it loads of times in the past.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out, deleting the two test orders and upgrading MySQL caused some  sort of anomaly where when a customer placed an order it somehow reused one of the test order ids (and i saw the test products on the order and test shipping details etc).

Incase this helps someone in the future, I recreated the customer orders in the backend, made them aware and deleted the old one - that solved the issue.

I did actually alter the varian/db.php function to exclude the error (and it broke the grids design but this clarified the cause for me)

Hope this helps someone

Comment: You can also accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can update the rewritten grid file's function with below,

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
   $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
   .........
   .........

   // Add this line before the setCollection Function
   $collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');

   $this->setCollection($collection);
   return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```